# How to centralize data encryption and decryption in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

I have two functions to encrypt and decrypt data.

My current code is as below. I have entity class, DTO class, repository and service class.
The name need to be encrypted before save to database and to be decrypted when retrieve from database.

Lets say I have 10 different entity classes need to do the encryption and decryption data, I need to add the encryption and decryption function to each service class as below codes.

Is there any way to do all the encryption and decryption data in one service class for all the entity? like overriding the Get and Set method in entity? Anyone can advice? Thanks a lot.

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Customer {
        private Long id;
        private String name;
        private String contact;
    }
```

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class CustomerDTO {
        private String name;
    }
```

```
    @Repository
    public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{
    
    }
```

```
    @Service
    public class CustomerService {

         @Autowired
         private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

         @Autowired
         private EncrytionService encrytionService;

         public void save(String name){
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setName(encrytionService.doEncrypt(name));
            customerRepository.save(customer);
         }

         public CustomerDTO getCustomer(Long customerId) {
            Customer customer = customerRepository.findById(customerId);
            CustomerDTO dto = new CustomerDTO();
            dto.setName(encrytionService.doDecrypt(customer.getName()));

            return dto;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think you could do this with reflection

Comment: There are databases with several levels of encryption, also on columns. With encryption you can forget queries, similarity searches and such. You could store an entire name+address+contact info block encrypted. Everything else is unnecessary overhead. With lazy conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure there is a way to do that easily (kinda out-of-the-box way), but maybe you could try to implement something yourself using JPA lifecycle events and `EntityListener`.

For example:

```java
// this is going to be our EntityListener
public class SensitiveDataListener {
 
    @PrePersist
    void beforeAnyPersist(Customer customer) {
        // encrypt what you need and set
        // e.g. customer.setName(encrytionService.doEncrypt(customer.getName()));
    }
   
    // after an entity has been loaded
    @PostLoad
    void afterLoad(Customer customer) {
        // decrypt what you need
    }
}

// and this is how you add it to your entity
@EntityListeners(SensitiveDataListener.class)
@Entity
public class Customer {
    //...
}
```

A good question here would be - ok I have multiple entities, what do I do - create multiple `**Listener` classes? In general, no. Your listener can "handle" multiple entities, but how to make it happen - depends on what you need - for instance, if you need to encrypt/decrypt different fields in different entity that's one case, and if you need encrypt/decrypt let's say `name` and you have this field in different entities, that would be another case and another solution. Also, you might want to encrypt everything and again that would be a different solution because it is yet another use case.

If it is the same field you could probably "unify" you entities (but keep in mind sometimes it is not a good idea when your entities implement some interfaces):

```java
public interface Sensitive {
    void setName(final Date date);
}

@EntityListeners(SensitiveDataListener.class)
@Entity
public class Entity1 implements Sensitive {
    // override setName
}

@EntityListeners(SensitiveDataListener.class)
@Entity
public class Entity2 implements Sensitive {
    // override setName
}

// but then your SensitiveDataListener will look like this
public class SensitiveDataListener {
 
    @PrePersist
    void beforeAnyPersist(Sensitive entity) {
        // encrypt what you need and set
        // e.g. entity.setName(encrytionService.doEncrypt(entity.getName()));
    }
   
    // after an entity has been loaded
    @PostLoad
    void afterLoad(Sensitive entity) {
        // decrypt what you need
    }
}
```

Maybe you could also use [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html), assuming your field is `String` and encoded value is also `String` you could create converter which will encode/decode your stuff, but then you need to add it to every field (in every entity) you want to encode.

Something like this:

```java
@Convert(converter = MyAttributeConverter.class)
private String name; // this is entity field
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. It helps a lot . Let's say I wanted to encryt different fields in different entity, I can use the same method like void beforeAnyPersist(Customer customer, Staff staff) { } or create a new method?

Comment: @Teong that won't work. method signature in general is something like `void someName(entity)`, so maybe you could try to add several methods like `@PrePersist beforeAnyPersist(Customer customer) { }` and `@PrePersist beforeAnyPersist(Staff staff) { }` in the same listener class.